# load a php page inside a html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm using this code  to load a php page inside a html page using javascipt , but it doesn't work. the code is below :

```
<html>
....
<div id="home" style="background: #000;background-image: none;height:100%;"></div>
    <script>
    $('#home').load('http://www.website.com/file/index.php').trigger("create");
    </script>
</html>
```

the php file exists and works fine but it doesn't show up in the actual page . If you have modification i can make i'll be thankful

Comment: Is it actually returning the data? With firefox/chrome developer tools (F12), check the data being returned in the call.

Comment: access oigin null thing ... again i don't know to solve this

Answer (score 3):

If you remote website is not in same server you can't do it, for [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) security restrictions, as specified in the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation.

But, you will have a proxy script like:

**proxyScript.php**

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.website.com/file/index.php"); ?>
```

And, now, you can: `$('#home').load('proxyScripts.php').trigger("create");`

Or you will configure your remote server to accept remote request, read: [How to use Cross domain Ajax request](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.mx/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#0)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with javascript happening AFTER php happens.

Why not switch it with

include('http://www.website.com/file/index.php');

if your hiding that div you could just use javascript to show / hide the div based on what ever happens.  Dont try to lead the php file when its hovered or clicked or w/e.  Load it first and just display it with js.

Comment: when i put include instead of load . all the page changes , but that div is inside menu and buttons in bottom .

Comment: I don't think I can help more without see'ing the page or the correct code. =[